# laravel videos not in the public folder

Tags: laravel, storage, public, protected

I have a laravel application (5.4)

Every user has a folder under /public where the admin can upload (via FTP) some videos for the users to see. Every user have different Videos.

The problem i have now is, that everything in the public folder is accessible. Also if the user is not logged in. How to avoid this?

Comment: you need to store them as private files, then when user hits a link you make sure it is logged and have access to the link

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose we have 2 users with these usernames:

- john
- Sarah

then you would have 2 folders:

- `storage/app/john`
- `storage/app/sarah`

now to access john's files, you should have in your routes/web.php the following:

`Route::get('/file/{username}/{name}','FilesController@getFile');`

then in the `FilesController` add this function:

```
public function getFile($username,$name){
   if(!Auth::user()){
       //user is not logged in
       return response(null,403)
    }
   $auth_user = Auth::user()->username;
   if($username === $auth_user){
    //continue with the request

      $exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists($username .'/'. $name);
     if(!$exists){
         // file not found
         return response(null,404);
     }
      $file = Storage::get($username .'/'. $name);
      return response($file);
   }else{
     // the user doesn't have access
   }
}
```

i didn't test this so if you had issues let me know

[More on laravel storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#introduction)

Comment: Thx for the solution. Every logged in user can access their videos and cant access other users videos. The problem is, when i change the url to the mp4 file, also if no one is logged in, i can see it. Moving it to the storage folder and i have no access on it, also when logged in.

Comment: you only can access the files through this function, direct link to the file won't work because it's not in the `storage/app/public` folder

Comment: so how is it possible to pass the files to the video or img tag in html?

Comment: through this `return response()->file(storage_path('app',$username .'/'. $name));`